# SDL2 on Windows steals my stdout and stderr

Tags: visual-c++, linker, console-application, stdout, sdl-2

So I am using SDL2, built as static library, on Windows 64bit.
And SDL2 stops your stdout and stderr from reaching the console.

Now, I've read the [FAQ](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Console) on this.
But:

- NO_STDIO_REDIRECT symbol is for SDL1.2 only, and is not used in SDL2.
- freopen() trick does not work, in any incantation.
- I link my app as a console app.
- I do not link against SDL2main convenience library.

I use visual C from 2013 suite, on the command line.
This is my linker invokation:

*LINK.EXE /OUT:giver.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /NOLOGO  c:/Users/bram/Desktop/src/opende/lib/Release/ode.lib  C:/Users/bram/Desktop/src/SDL2-2.0.3/VisualC/S
DL/x64/Debug/SDL2.lib  winmm.lib ws2_32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib version.lib imm32.lib  OpenGL32.lib sdlmain.obj gl3w.obj libpi.lib libbase.lib*

Yet, no std output for me.
How on earth do I stop SDL2 from stealing my output?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I gave up on the command-line interface, and capitulated. Now I use a visual studio project. I never found out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple SDL2 program and used the [default x64 SDL2.0.3 VC .lib/.dll's](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.3-VC.zip) that can be found from libsdl.org and managed to compile with VS2013 on Win7 x64 and get console output with printf/SDL_Log. Hopefully this helps.

Here's the program:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Test", 
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                        800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

  SDL_Surface* screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

  SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0x0c, 0xd6, 0xe8));
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

  printf("printf: Hello World\n");
  SDL_Log("SDL_Log: Hello World\n");

  SDL_Delay(2500);

  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Here's how I compiled (change your include/link directories appropriately):

```
cl hello_SDL2.cpp /MD /I C:\vs_sdl\include /link C:\vs_sdl\lib\x64\SDL2.lib  C:\vs_sdl\lib\x64\SDL2main.lib /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

The program brings up a window for a few seconds and outputs the following to the console:

```
printf: Hello World
SDL_Log: Hello World
```